# run ntpdate from rc.local

Tags: centos6, sh, rc.local

My `/etc/rc.local` is:

```
#!/bin/sh

touch /var/lock/subsys/local

/data/automatic/ntpdate.sh
```

My `/data/automatic/ntpdate.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "RWQERWER" >> /data/logs/1.log
ntpdate ntp.fudan.edu.cn >> /data/logs/1.log
```

The echo "RW...." is worked,ntp has installed. ntpdate.sh is 744 ,
but ntpdate ntp.fudan.edu.cn is run failed.

Outside at bash command line ,the `/data/automatic/ntpdate.sh` and `ntpdate ntp.fudan.edu.cn >> /data/logs/1.log` both run successfully .

What should I do ? Thanks first !

Comment: What does "is run failed" means? Does `ntpdate`  report an error into `/data/logs/1.log`? Maybe you get more info if  you redirect STDERR as well: `ntpdate ntp.fudan.edu.cn >> /data/logs/1.log 2>&1`

Comment: I think the issue is that in bash script you must specify full path to the ntpdate. Try to replace ntpdate ntp.fudan.edu.cn on /usr/sbin/ntpdate ntp.fudan.edu.cn

Comment: @ALex_hha: On my C6.4 the PATH that rc.local admits to is /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin - it's very strange.

Comment: That 's the point ! bash and sh .... but even if I use the full path , it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[ntpdate](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate) is depreciated. You should install the NTP client and configure the ntpd daemon configuration file `/etc/ntp.conf`:

```
# cat /etc/ntp.conf | grep -v ^# | grep -v ^$
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1
server europe.pool.ntp.org
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
```

And start the daemon

```
# service ntpd start
```

Comment: no.I don't mean to use ntpd service ,just the ntpdate ,when ntpdate running,ntpd should closed.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you want to get by running ntpdate once at system startup?

Comment: @mike: Are you aware of the differences between `ntpdate` and `ntpd`? `ntpdate` will update the time once when you run it,  whereas `ntpd` will continually update the time.

Comment: I just want to use ntpdate for once update time , not a ntpd service .

Comment: @mike - Alex_hha has the right answer. [ntpdate](https://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Dev/DeprecatingNtpdate) has been deprecated. You should be running the NTP client service.

Comment: @kce The question is how to make ntpdate work. He's even explicitly stated that he does NOT want to use a service. So no, this neither a right or wrong answer... it's no answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you (and I get the same problem) can't capture the output of the command when run from rc.local.

If you want to capture it you can do something like

```
out=$(ntpdate ntp.fudan.edu.cn 2>&1)
echo $out >>/data/logs/1.log
```

which just worked on a system I have to hand.

Comment: Actually , it's a very simple question ,you just use my code like my way ,and you will figure out .

Comment: @mike: I'm sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I try my best to let you understand ,but I am an Aisan , english is so difficult to me . aplogizes!